# Instantiating a generic field of a class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constructor, field

Is there a way to have a generic field in a class to specialize to a specific type in the constructor?

For example:

```
class concreteClass1
{
    private int a;
    public concreteClass1( int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class concreteClass2
{
    string b;
    public concreteClass2(string b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class A<T>
{
    private T field;
    public A(int x)
    {
        field = new concreteClass1(x); //error here CS0029
    }

    public A(string y)
    {
        field = new concreteClass2(y); //error here CS0029
    }
}
```

So `T` can be either `concreteClass1` or `concreteClass1` and their respective ctors will have different signatures.

Comment: What do you want to do when someone writes: `new A<concereteClass2>(42);`?

Comment: Then `A` will have an `concreteClass1` field I could read and write to. @Servy

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to do that requires you to do this?

Comment: @kuhaku Sorry, typo, I meant to mismatch them.  See edit.

Comment: @Servy I haven't thought about it yet, maybe it will throw an exception.

Comment: Generic code should be generic.  The whole point of generic code is that it will work regardless of what specific type is used.  The fact that your code doesn't, and in fact only works when exactly one type is used, means that it's not actually generic, and so you shouldn't be using generics.

Comment: @juharr I'm trying to have a `Car` class that will have an energy source of either electric or gas powered. I wanted to avoid having both `Electric` and `Fuel` types in `Car` as fields and to instantiate only one of them in the appropriate ctor.

Comment: @Servy I see, makes sense.

Comment: What prevents you from creating an abstract class `EnergySource` and deriving `Electric` and `Fuel` from it?

Comment: @adjan because the base class will have to have all of the public methods of both derivatives as virtual, which is a little not DRY.

Comment: The code above is an anti-pattern, that's why it's not allowed. @Servy is right, your concrete implementation doesn't allow for abstraction. What's more, if you want these two types to both inherit from the same base class, it's confusing that one constructor takes a string and one takes an int. However, you can have a `public bool MyMethod<T>(T t) where T : IMyInterface { }` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx). Then you have your concrete classes derive from the interface.

Comment: @kuhaku That sounds like `Electric` and `Fuel` should have a common interface or base class.  Not sure what you are doing that requires it to be more than a simple enum even.

Comment: This will force me to make empty implementations of the public methods of `Fuel` in `Electric` and vice versa because the common base will have to have both, I guess I'll just keep it simple and have two fields in `Car` for `Electric` and `Fuel`. @juharr

Comment: @kuhaku Then your oo is generally flawed.

Comment: Or maybe you should even have an `ElectricCar` and a `FuelCar` classes that implement a `ICar` interface.  It's really hard to say without seeing your current implementation and I'm not sure that type of thing would be on topic here anyway.

Comment: +1 on XY problem. When we find ourselves trying to solve this problem, the real problem is that we *have* the problem. It's better to design classes so that we don't find ourselves trying to figure things like this out. It never ends well. I apologize - that sounds so very, very unhelpful. (But that's the nature of the XY problem.) I strongly recommend learning about dependency injection. It helps us to write classes that depend on abstractions instead of classes that create more classes.

Comment: One of the first things taught in OOP is inheritance, but trying to compose complex behaviors with inheritance fails more often than it succeeds. Something else to read about is "favor composition over inheritance." If you need classes that do different things, don't try to make them inherit from each other. Write different classes that do different things and then write classes that bring them together.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm spamming. If the classes you're working with are `ElectricCar` and `FuelCar`, please post the question using those classes. That will make it easier to understand the relationship between classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor this to use dependency injection. That way the class doesn't contain code to create other classes that it depends on, like `myConcreteField = new ConcreteA<T>(4);`. Dependency injection is used to keep code from getting tied into difficult knots like this.

(Your example is very, very abstract, which makes it a little difficult. If you use class names like "Concrete" and "Implementation" then it makes the answer harder to read because we use those same words to describe concepts.)

Instead, whatever that `Concrete` thing is, declare an interface, like

```
public interface ISomethingThatTheOtherClassNeeds<T>
{
    public int MySomething {get;set;}
}

public class SomethingThatTheOtherClassNeeds : ISomethingThatTheOtherClassNeeds<string>
{
    public int MySomething {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your `Implementation` class:

```
class Implementation<T>
{
    private readonly ISomethingThatTheOtherClassNeeds<T> _something;

    public Implementation(ISomethingThatTheOtherClassNeeds<T> something)
    {
        _something = something;
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.Write(_something.MySomething.ToString());
    }
}
```

The difference is that instead of being responsible for creating whatever that class is, it's passed to `Implementation` in the constructor. `Implementation` doesn't even know what the class is - it just knows that it matches the interface.

This is especially helpful if those other classes in turn depend on more classes. If you're creating them by calling `new` in your class then that class has to know how to create those classes.

Then to wire it up you would use a dependency injection container like Windsor, Unity, Autofac, and many more. That's not very commonly done with console applications, but I'm guessing this is more experimental than real.

Answer (score 1):

Well this was a bit tricky due to having to convert types. Maybe this will work for you?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myImplementation = new Implementation<int>(4);
        var myImplementation2 = new Implementation<string>("Hello World");

        Console.WriteLine(myImplementation.myConcreteField); // outputs 4!
        Console.WriteLine(myImplementation2.myConcreteField); // outputs Hello World
    }
}

abstract class MyAbstract<T>
{
    public T MySomething;
    public MyAbstract(T something)
    {
        MySomething = something;
    }
}

class ConcreteA<T> : MyAbstract<T>
{
    public ConcreteA(int something) : base((T)Convert.ChangeType(something, typeof(T)))
    {
    }
}

class ConcreteB<T> : MyAbstract<T>
{
    public ConcreteB(string something) : base((T)Convert.ChangeType(something, typeof(T)))
    {
    }
}

class Implementation<T>
{
    public MyAbstract<T> myConcreteField;

    public Implementation(T a)
    {
        myConcreteField = new ConcreteA<T>(4);
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.Write(myConcreteField.MySomething.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this better than using `object` instead of a generic type argument? If you're not using the class as a generic class... don't make it generic.

Comment: @Luaan well myConcreteField is already casted to the correct type. Other than that, no reason I think.